# Grails, create-plugin not auto reloading changes

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am on Grails 2.3.7.

I have a main application called momain, and have created a plugin called motest.

I then in the BuildConfig.groovy add the line:

grails.plugin.location.'motest' = "../motest"

No other references to the plugin has been made. I add a controller to motest and I can render some random text when reached in the browser.

However, when I change the output of the render and hit refresh in the browser, the changes are not reloaded from the code in the plugin! I have to run grails run-app for them to be picked up.

How can I make Grails reload changes for things in the plugin? Otherwise it becomes really tedious to separate functionality to plugins/modules.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This seems to occur when I switch from

build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

to

build ":jetty:2.0.3"

It seems to be a problem related to jetty...

Comment: Did you make your plugin support reloading? http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html#participatingInAutoReloadEvents

Comment: @JoshuaMoore you don't need to manually reload controllers and views of your plugin. The `onChange` event is used when you have other non standard Grails resources.

Comment: @Samson are you running your plugin from inside an IDE or though console?

Comment: @SérgioMichels I am running it from console. This problem only occurs when I am using Jetty though. Tomcat works fine, but I dont like the way it is non-locking when the browser refreshes.

Comment: Running from the console you need to add the reloading flag: `grails run-app -reloading`